# How to add multiple polygons in leaflet map using r loop?

Tags: r, maps, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm trying to add multiple polygon to leaflet world map, according to a number of lists of country code. And I was trying to use R loop to add the polygon. Here's the code that I manually add polygons from list 1:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)
library(tidyverse)

countries_1 <- c('PAK','TUR','BGR')

adm1 <- getData('GADM', country='PAK', level=0)
adm2 <- getData('GADM', country= 'TUR', level=0)
adm3 <- getData('GADM', country= 'BGR', level=0)


leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data=adm1, weight = 3, fillColor = 'purple', color = 'purple') %>%
  addPolygons(data=adm2, weight = 3, fillColor = 'purple', color = 'purple') %>%
  addPolygons(data=adm3, weight = 3, fillColor = 'purple', color = 'purple')
```

I am thinking using the loop to add multiple polygon layers so that for list_n:

```
 countries_n <- ('ctry1','ctry2','ctry3',...'ctryn') 

 for (i in country_n) {

   countries <-  basemap %>% addPolygons(data=getData('GADM',country = i, level = 0),
  weight = 3, fillColor = 'purple', color = 'purple')

  }
```

The question is how can I embed the loop to "leflet() %>%" ?

*Note here: 
If try to add multiple data in addPolygons(), it will plot only the first element in the data, in below case, only country 'PAK' will be ploted:

```
addPolygons(data=c('PAK','TUR'), weight = 3, fillColor = 'purple', color = 'purple')
```

Comment: Can't you just merge the data and map country to a variable?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik please read the Note. If you merge them into a variable, it'll only plot the first element in the list.

Comment: It looks like you are adding a base map every time you go through the loop, can you instead create `countries` in a loop pasted string of polygons then just pipe that to the end of your `leaflet%>%addTiles%>%`. You could just paste with the pipe command at the end of each iteration in it inside the loop....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution using packages **sf** and **mapview**. Note that this is currently only possible using the develop version of **mapview** (see commented out `devtools::install_github()`

```
# devtools::install_github("r-spatial/mapview@develop")
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(raster)

countries_1 <- c('PAK','TUR','BGR')

dat_list = lapply(countries_1, function(i) {
  st_as_sf(getData("GADM", country = i, level = 0))
})

m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()

for (i in dat_list) {
  m = mapview::addFeatures(map = m, 
                           data = i, 
                           weight = 3, 
                           fillColor = 'purple', 
                           color = 'purple')
}

m
```

Note that `addFeatures` is type agnostic, so any combination of points, lines and/or polygons will work here.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Though I managed to apply my loop using the old method..