# How to add multiple polygons and layers in leaflet with a for loop?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I have created a map in leaflet with numerous polygons by breaking the larger dataset down into smaller ones based on their fuel types. The map works great and as intended, however, I want to slim my code down with either a function or a for loop that will reproduce the numerous polygon layers.

I have included my code for the map below and as you can see it is a lot. I found this post, [How to add multiple polygons in leaflet map using r loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396743/how-to-add-multiple-polygons-in-leaflet-map-using-r-loop), but am still having trouble with this particular issue since I am trying create multiple polygons from total_ERCOT, head included below, by fuel type without having to subset the data into smaller data sets (ERCOT_gas, ERCOT_wind, etc.). Any help would be much appreciated!

```
head(total_ERCOT)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 13 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -97.60523 ymin: 29.26259 xmax: -95.42412 ymax: 31.86308
geographic CRS: NAD83
# A tibble: 6 x 14
# Groups:   NAME, FUEL [3]
  GEOID NAME  `UNIT NAME` `UNIT CODE` FUEL  ZONE  `IN SERVICE` CAPACITY county_capacity   age                  geometry county_age county_fuel_cap~
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr> <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>        <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>      <dbl>            <dbl>
1 48309 MCLE~ SANDY CREE~ SCES_UNIT1  COAL  NORTH         2013     933.            948.     8 (((-97.27726 31.74549, -~       4.33             933.
2 48157 FORT~ W A PARISH~ WAP_WAP_G5  COAL  HOUS~         1977     664            4291     44 (((-96.01644 29.6271, -9~      37.1             2514 
3 48157 FORT~ W A PARISH~ WAP_WAP_G6  COAL  HOUS~         1978     663            4291     43 (((-96.01644 29.6271, -9~      37.1             2514 
4 48157 FORT~ W A PARISH~ WAP_WAP_G7  COAL  HOUS~         1980     577            4291     41 (((-96.01644 29.6271, -9~      37.1             2514 
5 48157 FORT~ W A PARISH~ WAP_WAP_G8  COAL  HOUS~         1982     610            4291     39 (((-96.01644 29.6271, -9~      37.1             2514 
6 48149 FAYE~ FAYETTE PO~ FPPYD1_FPP~ COAL  SOUTH         1979     603            1841     42 (((-97.08646 29.9943, -9~      23.4             1657
```

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = ERCOT_counties, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              fillColor = ~pal(county_capacity), 
              label = ~paste0(NAME, ": ", format(round(as.numeric(county_capacity, 0)), 
                                                 big.mark = ","), " MW ", 
                              " Average Generation Facility Age: ", round(county_age, 2), " Years", 
                              " Zone: ", ZONE),group = "Total Capacity") %>%
  addPolygons(data = ERCOT_gas, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              fillColor = ~pal(county_gas_capacity), 
              label = ~paste0(NAME, ": ", format(round(as.numeric(county_gas_capacity, 0)), 
                                                 big.mark = ","), " MW ", 
                              " Average Gas Facility Age: ", round(county_gas_age, 2), " Years", 
                              " Zone: ", ZONE), group = "Gas Capacity") %>%
  addPolygons(data = ERCOT_wind, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              fillColor = ~pal(county_wind_capacity), 
              label = ~paste0(NAME, ": ", format(round(as.numeric(county_wind_capacity, 0)), 
                                                 big.mark = ","), " MW ",
                              " Average Wind Facility Age: ", round(county_wind_age, 2), " Years", 
                              " Zone: ", ZONE), group = "Wind Capacity") %>%
  addPolygons(data = ERCOT_solar, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              fillColor = ~pal(county_solar_capacity), 
              label = ~paste0(NAME, ": ", format(round(as.numeric(county_solar_capacity, 0)), 
                                                 big.mark = ","), " MW ",
                              " Average Solar Facility Age: ", round(county_solar_age, 2), " Years", 
                              " Zone: ", ZONE), group = "Solar Capacity") %>%
  addPolygons(data = ERCOT_coal, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              fillColor = ~pal(county_coal_capacity), 
              label = ~paste0(NAME, ": ", format(round(as.numeric(county_coal_capacity, 0)), 
                                                 big.mark = ","), " MW ",
                              " Average Coal Facility Age: ", round(county_coal_age, 2), " Years", 
                              " Zone: ", ZONE), group = "Coal Capacity") %>%
  addPolygons(data = ERCOT_nuclear, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              fillColor = ~pal(county_nuclear_capacity), 
              label = ~paste0(NAME, ": ", format(round(as.numeric(county_nuclear_capacity, 0)), 
                                                 big.mark = ","), " MW ",
                              " Average Nuclear Facility Age: ", round(county_nuclear_age, 2), " Years", 
                              " Zone: ", ZONE), group = "Nuclear Capacity") %>%
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c("Total Capacity", "Gas Capacity", "Wind Capacity", "Solar Capacity", "Coal Capacity", "Nuclear Capacity"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

Comment: Can you somehow provide an example data for us?

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
# Create the underlying map
map <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles()

# Loop over various polygons to include.
for (...) {
    map <- map %>%
            addPolygons(...)
}

map %>%
    addLayersControl(...)
```

You can even build the `overlayGroups` vector inside the for loop.